# how to pass value form span id to form fields in ruby on rails?

Tags: javascript, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

In my edit view I have span giving me lat and long (using javascript). When I make span with correct id, the value is being passed in it:

```
<span id="gmaps-output-latitude"></span>
```

But when I put it into hidden field, the value is nil:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :lat, id: 'gmaps-output-latitude' %>
```

Any idea what I'm missing? These values are given by gem 'gmaps-autocomplete-rails'.

Comment: have you found how to do it?